# Any way to prevent scrolling to top in the inner javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

What's the javascript/jQuery solution to prevent from scrolling to the top when a link is clicked **for inner javascript function** `inner()`?

The solution should be in the inner function. Is it possible do not pass event as a parameter?  The other solutions are provided in the code below with explanations, however no one works as a solution in the `inner()`. The code is provided below. **Please scroll to the lowest link.** The solution is needed for the lowest link in the `inner()` function.

Here is the [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/guxdku9w/1/):

**html:**

```
<div>
    <p><a href="#">it jumps</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">it jumps</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">it jumps</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">it jumps</a></p>
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="jsSolution">no jumps - jsSolution</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" id="jqSolution">no jumps - jqSolution</a></p>
    <p><a href="#!">no jumps - html Solution</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" id="problem">how to prevent this from jumping - javascript solution in the add() function</a></p>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    function inner(){


        //prevent from scrolling to top here - solution is needed here;

        return 4;
    }
    function add() {
        alert('how to prevent jumping to top in the add function');
        var counter = 0;
        var res=inner();
        alert(res);//4
        //some code goes here
        //and here
        //this doesn't work e.preventDefault();
        return counter; 
    }
    $('#jqSolution').click(function(e) {
     //return false; 
     e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
    });
    $('#problem').click(function(e) {
         add();
    });
});
```

**jQuery library is included.**

**css:**

```
div{
border:1px solid red;
    width:200px;
}
p{
    padding:50px;
}
```

Thank you.

P.S. The links href="#" can not be changed, the javascript code should not be destroyed.

Comment: But changing the links href="#" is the solution

Comment: @George Jempty: You are right. However, I should not change the html part. The part where I can change the code (the preferable part) is inner() function. Or somewhere around there. Thank you.

Comment: But why it has to be in inner function???

Comment: I'm looking for an answer if it is possible. If you use it in the outer function where there is if-else statement and return false but inner() function is called when else is true, then there is a problem: it will "return false;" to prevent jumping for other if-else cases as well which is bad.

Comment: Most browsers pass event object by default, but better is too explecitely passes it to inner method as in posted answer

Comment: Downvoters please comment. Didn't I investigate the issue? Didn't I provide the code? Poor explanation? Not an SO question? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I got you completely, but you can just use preventDefault so that the default action of anchor tags is not executed. Js made some changes to your fiddle to make it work :-

http://jsfiddle.net/sahilbatla/guxdku9w/2/

```
$(function(){
    function inner(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //prevent from scrolling to top here - solution is needed here;

        return 4;
    }
    function add(e) {
        alert('how to prevent jumping to top in the add function');
        var counter = 0;
        var res=inner(e);
        alert(res);//4
        return counter; 
    }
    $('#jqSolution').click(function(e) {
     //return false; // prevent default click action from happening
     e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
    });

    $('#problem').click(function(e) {
         add(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: So you pass the parameter through all functions down to the inner function to preventDefault. Thank you for your solution. That's what I think as an option, however there may be more elegant way? Thank you.

Comment: One solution will be to use e.preventDefault() in the click event itself,saving the hassle of passing the event variable